# Why am I getting a 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports' error?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, import

Why my javascript throw me a 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports' error?

I have two file (app.js, **util**.js)
compiled from ts (app.ts, __util.ts)

When I use import { Time } from "../website/**util**";

vscode didn't give me a error or warning

but when I run index.html (script src = website/tscache/app.js) on safari, and open inspect elements, I received error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports
```

When I open file app.js, I saw:

```
File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES module.ts(80001)
(property) __esModule: true
```

that made me confused, when I compile ts, I didn't receive error, at app.js, it just a warning, when I run on browser, I received an error. And now I have no idea how to fix it.

Some Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2nRr.jpg)
[image]
[image]
[image]

tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {

        "outDir": "../website/tscache",
    
    },

    "include": [
        "/Users/user/Desktop/projects/ts/website/"
    ]
    ,

    "exclude": [
        "."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Show your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)